# How to get min and max values of ranges with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, range, max, min

I wonder if there are specific numpy functions to get the heighest and lowest values columns of my ranges.

For ranges you can assume that every first dimension of my numpy array respresents the horizontal row of my image.

I draw lines in each row of my image to different coordinates.

I need to know the start and endpoint of each line in each row.

Assume I have the following array:

EDIT:
I choose a bad range. This is better

```
a = np.array([[0, 1],[0, 2],[0, 3],[0, 4],[1, 0],[1, 1],[1, 2],[1, 3],[1, 4],[1,5],[3, 0],[3, 1],[3, 2],[3, 3],[3, 4],[4, 0],[4, 3],[4, 4],[5,0]])
```

What I'd like to have is

maxvalues/endpoints:

```
array([[0, 4],[1, 5],[3, 4],[4, 4],[5,0]])
```

minvalues/startpoints:

```
array([[0, 1],[1, 0],[3, 0],[4, 0],[5,0]])
```

I would loop over the whole array with if conditions and compare row values, but this way I also don't know if it makes sense to use numpy at all for this task.

I'm aware of np.amin/amax(array,axis) use, but not how to define efficient ranges.

EDIT2:

So the only solution I see in the moment is to do something like that:

```
for i in image_height:
    range_array = a[a[:,0] == i]
    min = np.amin(range_array,0)
    max = np.amax(range_array,0)
```

Comment: I do not understand the logic behind your desired output. Why is `[0,4]` the first element of `maxvalues`? Why is `[4,0]` the last element of `minvalues`?

Comment: Sorry. This is the meaning of my ranges i want to adress for the first dimension of my array values 0,1,3,4 ... My idea is. I want to draw red lines in an image for each image row. Those values are my pixel coordinates with red color. What I need is start and endpoint coordinates. Eg. redraw the line with another color.

Comment: Your example is sorted.  Is that true for your actual data?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thank you for that question. I guess I would sort the data before processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea here is to use `np.unique` to pull the first unique value from `a[:, 0]`, and then ensure that the array is ordered in the proper way to return either the minimum or maximum results.  If you don't believe the array will be sorted, simply set the `sort` flag to `True`

---

```
def get_extrema(a, min=False, sort=False):
    """Finds the minimum or maximum value for each row of an array"""

    if sort:
        a = a[np.lexsort([a[:, 1], a[:, 0]])]

    if not min:
        a = np.flip(a, 0)

    _, idx = np.unique(a[:, 0], return_index=True)

    return a[idx]
```

```
>>> get_extrema(a)
array([[0, 4],
       [1, 5],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 4],
       [5, 0]])
>>> get_extrema(a, min=True)
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [3, 0],
       [4, 0],
       [5, 0]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution (using pandas):

Input:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
minvalues = df.groupby([0]).min().reset_index().values
maxvalues = df.groupby([0]).max().reset_index().values
```

If you want to keep the min and max values as pandas dataframes, then take out the `.values`.

Output:

```
minvalues: array([[0, 1],[1, 0],[3, 0],[4, 0],[5, 0]], dtype=int64)
maxvalues: array([[0, 4],[1, 5],[3, 4],[4, 4],[5, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Ah. Tricky solution! But what if I change the array slightly to this? a = np.array([[0, 1],[0, 2],[0, 3],[0, 4],[1, 0],[1, 1],[1, 2],[1, 3],[1, 4],[1,5],[3, 0],[3, 1],[3, 2],[3, 3],[3, 4],[4, 0],[4, 3],[4, 4],[5,0]]) Can you help again please?

Comment: Yeah, I accidentally used `argmin` and `argmax` when I should have been using `amin` and `amax`. I have corrected that.

Comment: It doesn't work if I use the area from my last comment:  amax: array([[1, 5]])

Comment: Oh, I see what you're asking now. Let me get back to you on that.

Comment: Okay, I have corrected my code. I am a bit more comfortable with pandas, so that's what I used.

Comment: I like that! Any tutorials on pandas you recommend? Thank you!

Comment: The [Python Data Science Handbook](https://www.amazon.com/Python-Data-Science-Handbook-Essential/dp/1491912057) by Jake VanderPlas is an amazing book. You can read it free online on his [site](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/). A good introduction to Pandas was given by [Brandon Rhodes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5JnMutdy6Fw&feature=youtu.be) at a Pycon. Awesome video. Have fun!